# response.redirect and throw in catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

What will happen in the following scenario? Will it throw work after response.redirect?

Or do I need to use Response.Redirect in catch block of main method where it throws exception call stack....

```
try
{    
//code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{    
Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
throw;    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try? Interesting question though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you aren't supplying the parameter to indicate whether the current page should continue executing, it will automatically terminate the page by calling End().  Using the method with a single parameter is the same as calling the method with two parameters, with the second (endResponse) set to `true`. Since End() results in an exception being thrown, it won't ever reach your throw statement.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx

> When you use this method in a page
>   handler to terminate a request for one
>   page and start a new request for
>   another page, set endResponse to true
>   or call the Redirect method overload.
>   This method calls End for the original
>   request, which throws a
>   ThreadAbortException exception upon
>   completion.

If you want the page to continue executing you need to use the signature with two parameters and set the endResponse parameter to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

If you call Response.Redirect (without the overload) then it should immediately stop execution and so the throw won't be raised.

However, if you use the overload and pass in false eg. `Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", false)` then it will continue execution of the page and then redirect.

(At least, that is my understanding from [the documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx).